# Get bitwise and of all elements of an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, bitwise-operators

if i have and array like

```
$array=[11,11,13,18,19];
```

and i want to do a bitwise add operator for all elements like

```
echo $array[0]&$array[1]&$array[2];
```

What will be the logic and how to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with the following one-liner:

```php
echo array_reduce($array, fn($carry, $item) => $carry & $item, reset($array));
```

It uses [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/array_reduce) to 'loop' over the array, reducing it to one value. The callback function performs the bitwise operation.